# TinyMce not inserting <br />

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I'm using TinyMce to insert/edit a text from a database, but I don't know why the `<br />`'s are missing. There are no new lines, even if I hit ENTER or SHIFT + ENTER.

TinyMce init:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    mode : "textareas",
    theme : "simple",
    force_p_newlines : false,
    force_br_newlines : true,
    convert_newlines_to_brs : false
});
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the [TinyMCE documentation for `force_br_newlines`](http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:force_br_newlines):

> This option is deprecated as of 3.5 use forced_root_blocks: false instead to control p vs br behavior.

As of version 3.0a1, `forced_root_block` is enabled by default. [The documentation also says](http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:forced_root_block) that if you disable this option, Enter will produce a `<br />`, while Shift+Enter will produce a `<p>`.

Try this:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    mode : "textareas",
    theme : "simple",
    forced_root_block : false,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Update for version [6.1 or later](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/content-behavior-options/#newline_behavior):

```
newline_behavior: 'linebreak'
```